# Integral dependence over rings is transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-dependence

> Let $A\subset B\subset C$ be commutative rings. Suppose $B$ is integral over $A$, and $C$ is integral over $B$. Then I want to show that $C$ is integral over $A$.

To be integral means that for every $b\in B$, there exists a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$ such that $b$ is a root, i.e. $b^n+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1b+a_0=0$ for $a_{n-1},\ldots,a_0\in A$. Likewise, for any $c\in C$ we can write $c^k+b_{k-1}c^{k-1}+\cdots+b_1c+b_0=0$. Now, how can we write $c$ as a polynomial with coefficients in $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very standard but nontrivial result: see e.g. $\S$ 14.1 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

This occurs in the first section of a long chapter on integral extensions and is the fifth result in that section.  Especially, the proof uses the fact that if $R \subset S$ is a ring extension, then $\alpha \in S$ is integral over $R$ if and only if there is a subring $T$ with $R \subset R[\alpha] \subset T \subset S$ with $T$ finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be that complicated?  I read that section of the linked notes, and it just seems to boil down to (S integral over R) <=> (S f.g. as a module over R).  The forward way is trivial, and the reverse is pretty straightforward if you think about it.  From there it seems easy to show that being f.g. as a module is transitive.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: This is ancient by now, but purely for the sake of completeness, let me point out that the equivalence "(S integral over R) <=> (S f.g. as a module over R)" in the comment by @JeremySalwen is false: The "<==" part is true, but the "==>" part holds only "locally" (in the sense that: if $S$ is integral over $R$, then each finitely generated $R$-subalgebra of $S$ is also finitely generated as an $R$-module). This is a very useful fact, and indeed, once you know it, the question here becomes very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof for finitely generated algebras.

---

**Lemma 1**: Let $S$ be an algebra over $R$.  Then $\alpha\in S$ is integral over a $R$ iff $R[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as a module over R.

(Note that this lemma works even for $S$ not finitely generated over $R$).

**Proof**:

(Forward).  If $\alpha$ is integral over $R$, then there is some monic polyomial $f\in R[x]$ s.t. $f(\alpha)=\alpha^n+f_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+f_1\alpha+f_0=0$.  Thus $\alpha^n=-(f_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+f_1\alpha+f_0)$, and so any powers of $\alpha$ greater than or equal to $n$ can be rewritten in terms of powers of $\alpha$ lower than $n$.  Thus $R[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as a module by $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$.

(Reverse). If $R[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as a module over $R$, then let $\{g_1,\ldots,g_m\}\subseteq R[\alpha]$ be a finite set of generators.  We can choose some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that it is higher than the degree of every $g_i$.  Now consider $\alpha^k\in R[\alpha]$ is generated by these $g_i$, thus $\alpha^n=b_1 g_1+\cdots+b_m g_m$ for some $b_i\in R$.  But notice that the righthand side is all of degree lower than $k$, thus $\alpha^k-(b_1 g_1+\cdots+b_m g_m)=0$ is a monic polynomial in $R$ which is satisfied by $\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $R$.

---

**Lemma 2**: Let $S$ be a finitely generated algebra over $R$.  $S$ is integral over a ring $R$ iff $S$ is finitely generated as a module over $R$.

**Proof**:  Apply Lemma 1 to all the generators of $S$.

---

**Theorem (Integral dependence over rings is transitive)**:  Let $S$ be a finitely generated algebra over $R$, $T$ a finitely generated algebra over $S$.  If $S$ is integral over $R$, and $T$ is integral over $S$, then $T$ is integral over $R$.

**Proof**:

Applying Lemma 2, this is equivalent to showing being finitely generated as a module is transitive.  If we take $\{f_i\}$ generators of $T$ over $S$ and $\{g_i\}$ generators of $S$ over $R$ then $\{g_i f_j\}$ will form a set of generators of $T$ over $R$. The proof is left as an excercise for the reader.

(Hint: Write down an arbitrary element of $T$ in terms of the $f_i$ and elements of $S$, and then expand the elements of $S$ in terms of the $g_i$.)

Comment: I don't think you can prove Lemma 2 the way you do. It is not obvious that finite generation of $S$ as an $R$-module implies finite generation of $R\left[\alpha\right]$ as an $R$-module (where $\alpha$ is one of the generators). Submodules of finitely generated $R$-modules may and may not be finitely generated.