# Integral Closure is Integrally Closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Question:** Let $S$ be a commutative $R-$algebra, and let $T$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $S$. Show that the integral closure of $T$ in $S$ is $T$.

I understand that the ultimate goal is to suppose $b\in S$ is integral over $T$ and then show $b\in T$. Meaning we need to show that $b$ is integral over $R$ as well.

However I do not know what equivalent property of integral over $R$ I should aim for. Should I show that there is some polynomial, $p(x)$ over $R$ so that $p(b)= 0$ in $S$? Should I show that $R[b]$ is a finitely generated $R-$module?

Either way I have no idea how to get from $T$ being the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ and $b$ being integral over $T$ to $b$ being integral over $R$ in $S$.

Any suggestion for a particular direction would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676391/integral-dependence-over-rings-is-transitive) answer your question? Also, this is a standard result proved in many texts on commutative algebra, e.g., it's Corollary 5.5. in Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. My issue though is that T is a R-subalgebra of S and R is just the scalar ring. Unless we can relate R with R*1_S and perhaps if 1_S is in T? Then we can use this. @RichardD.James

Comment: What is your definition of $R$-algebra? For me, if $S$ is a commutative $R$-algebra, that means that $S$ is a commutative ring and there is a ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \to S$, and my definition of ring homomorphism includes that $\varphi(1) = 1$.