# Integral Closure of a Ring of Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm having trouble understanding why number rings are integrally closed, i.e. why any element of a number field $F$ that is integral over its ring of integers (or number ring) $\mathcal{O}_F$ is itself an element of $\mathcal{O}_F$. What would a proof look like?

Comment: If you have a number field $F$ (by which, I suppose, you mean a finitely generated algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$), what exactly do you mean by $\mathcal O_F$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. That was the notation we used for ring of integers/number ring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676391/integral-dependence-over-rings-is-transitive

Comment: One way to check that something is integral is to show that it is contained in a subring that is finitely generated as a module. Can you use that?

Comment: Ah, that's precisely what Pete suggests there.